# Magento 2 How to Change Estimate Shipping Default Country

Tags: magento2, shipping, configuration, default-values

I have **Magento 2.2.5** installed.

**General > Default Country is set to 'United Kingdom'** however on the 'Estimate Shipping' part of the cart page, the default country shown is United States (we don't even ship there).

**Can anyone please advise how to change that to United Kingdom?**

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 4):

The config for Estimate Shipping and Tax on cart page: **STORES > Configuration > SALES > Tax > Default Tax Destination Calculation**

[image]

Should try to clear Browser cache and local storage.